# incremental "lastmodified" not working in sqoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, teradata, sqoop

I'm trying sqoop to perform incremental import from Teradata DB to Hive. Below is the query:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:teradata://xxx.xxx.x.xx/DATABASE=DBN --driver com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver --username userN --password pass --query "SELECT alias.colA, alias.call_date, alias.colB, alias.colC FROM tableName alias where \$CONDITIONS" --target-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/staging.db/tableName -m 26 --check-column call_date --incremental append --split-by alias.colA --last-value '2016-02-01'
```

The column call_date is of DATE type, values in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

When I use `'append'` for `--incremental`, everything works fine. But when I put `'lastmodified'`, the following error is thrown:

```
ERROR util.SqlTypeMap: It seems like you are looking up a column that does not 
ERROR util.SqlTypeMap: exist in the table. Please ensure that you've specified 
ERROR util.SqlTypeMap: correct column names in Sqoop options.                  
ERROR tool.ImportTool: Imported Failed: column not found: call_date
```

I'm using `sqoop 1.4.4.2.1` on `HDP 2.1`
While Teradata DB is `14.10`

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: By looking at the error, did you provided column name correctly?

Comment: Yes, everything is correct. 
As I mentioned above as well, if I changed `lastmodified` to `append`, everything works fine.

Comment: Could be related to this bug in Teradata handling incremental lastmodified imports? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-2402

Answer (score 0):

I think, in case of query you can perform the last value check in the query itself some think like this

`"SELECT alias.colA, alias.call_date, alias.colB, alias.colC FROM tableName alias where call_date >'2016-02-01'  and \$CONDITIONS"`  .

Reference (refer section **Incrementally Updating Data in Hive  > 1.Ingest the data.**)

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/bk_dataintegration/content/incrementally-updating-hive-table-with-sqoop-and-ext-table.html